# ansible run series of tasks on multiple nodes

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

I have an ansible playbook which looks roughly like this:

```yaml
    - hosts: firstNode
      tasks:
      - name: create cluster
        shell: "cluster create command"

    - hosts: otherNodes
      serial: 1
      tasks:
      - name: joining cluster
        shell: "cluster join command"
```

`firstNode` is always a single host while `otherNodes` could be any number. 
 It's important that each command is executed in serial.  I would now like to insert a job before and after each `join command` to ensure that everything is working, so for a 3 node cluster the sequence would be the following jobs in serial

1. host 1 - create cluster
2. host 2 - check cluster status
3. host 2 - join cluster
4. host 2 - check node status
5. host 3 - check cluster status
6. host 3 - join cluster
7. host 3 - check node status

Is this possible with ansible?

Comment: Just add your tasks in your second play. They will be played in order, one host at a time since your have serial=1. If needed, your can use the fail module to stop the entire playbook when something goes wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add your commands to the tasks block:

```
- hosts: firstNode
  tasks:
  - name: create cluster
    shell: "cluster create command"

- hosts: otherNodes
  serial: 1
  tasks:
  - name: check cluster
    shell: "check cluster command"

  - name: joining cluster
    shell: "cluster join command"

  - name: check node
    shell: "check node command"
```